# Using `noexcept` on a function that returns a unordered_map

Tags: c++, noexcept

Is it safe to declare a function as `noexcept` if it initialises and returns a `std::unordered_map<int, string>`. As an example:

```
std::unordered_map<int, std::string> get_raw_num_map() noexcept
{
  return std::unordered_map<int, std::string>(
    {{1, "one"}, {2, "two"}, {3, "three"}, {4, "four"}, {5, "five"}, {6, "six"}, {7, "seven"}, {8, "eight"},
     {9, "nine"}, {10, "ten"}, {11, "eleven"}, {12, "twelve"}, {13, "thirteen"}, {14, "fourteen"}, {15, "fifteen"},
     {16, "sixteen"}, {17, "seventeen"}, {18, "eighteen"}, {19, "nineteen"}, {20, "twenty"}, {30, "thirty"},
     {40, "forty"}, {50, "fifty"}, {60, "sixty"}, {70, "seventy"}, {80, "eighty"}, {90, "ninety"},
     {100, "hundred"}, {1000, "thousand"}});
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "safe to declare a function as `noexcept`"? You can see that [`std::unordered_map`'s constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/unordered_map) and [`std::string`'s constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) might throw if allocation fails, but it might be considered acceptable to terminate when that happens

Comment: Note that once a function is `noexcept` it's very difficult to take it back. Any code that uses it might rely on it being `noexcept` so removing it in the future is a breaking change that requires careful inspection of anywhere it's called. Unlike many other breaking changes, like changing argument or return types, the compiler (at non that I know of) will help you with that. So it's often wise not to make use of `noexcept` unless you can be sure it will always be `noexcept` or if it has actual performance or safety implications (like move constructors and assignment operators or swap).

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I find this comment to be the most compelling argument against using `noexcept`. Taken in isolation, removing the ability to record and act on a memory allocation failure may be an appropriate course of action, but that ignores the downstream consequences.

Comment: it could make sense to use noexcept in this case. If unordered_map throws an exception in init, this would be a disaster in any case. So, forced termination could be an acceptable behavior.

Comment: Since your map is always the same, you could make it a global, and have the function return a `const` reference to it, in which case it truly would be `noexcept`. Though it would lock you into that approach. The only time this could generate an exception is during static initialization, at which time it's truly not possible to recover meaningfully.

Answer (score 6):

Construction of most collection types in C++ can throw, via allocation failing if nothing else. So a function returning  one can also throw, and should not be declared `noexcept`.